# How do I add newline/return character as delimiter on NCAR?

Tags: plot

I try using e.g.
`delimiter=\n` or
`delimiter=str_get_nl()`
but to no avail. Does anyone know what is the correct command?

Comment: How do you use it in a string? Could you give an example?

Comment: For e.g., "count=str_fields_count(data,delimiter)". However, it counts new line separately as some of my data are separated by newline.

Comment: This looks like it may or may not be pure Python even though there’s no tag for that. Is there a GIS component to your question?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the problem as follows.

```
data = "1 2 3 4 5 \n 6 7 8 9 10"

strlist = str_split(data, "\n")

data = strlist(0) + strlist(1)

print(str_fields_count(data, " ")) ;-- prints (0) 10
```

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work. I had tried delimiter = \n, \r, ~C~, str_get_nl(), tochar(10) but they doesn't work

Comment: Did you try `delimiter = inttochar(10)`?

Comment: I just tried this but it still doesn't work

Comment: For instance, my dataset is                                                            1 2 3 4 5 \n                                                                                        6 7 8 9 10                                                                                          I try to make the count=10 by using delimiter=" "+inttochar(10). However, I get the count separated like this instead count=                                                                   
(0) 5                                                                                                      (1) 5

Comment: `\n` is just a string with two characters in ncl, not a newline character.

Comment: Actually, I can't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to find out, for example, how many numbers are in the string after subtracting `\n`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I use '\nl' to show that the data is arranged such that the second set of numbers (6,7,8,9,10) is 'below' the first set as it is placed under a newline. As the second set is located on a new line, the str_field_count function calculate the count separately, e.g. 5 & 5 instead of 10 which I wanted.

Comment: I managed to get over this issue using a loop but I am still curious whether can I use a delimiter for newline as it will be much convenient.

Comment: I reviewed the docs, but I cannot find anything about escape characters.

Comment: Never mind thanks so much for your help!